# Convert byte array to produce different Audio Sound in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

I have an application to record the voice and save the file as Mp3 file.  I am able to create the MP3 file by converting the byte[] array.  However, I am curious to know How can we change the byte[] data to replicate different crazy sounds or voices.  The following is the code snippet used to convert the byte stream to mp3 sound.  Any Ideas!

```
 private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediaFile = await _fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        if (mediaFile != null)
        {
            using (var dataReader = new DataReader(_audioStream.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint) _audioStream.Size);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) _audioStream.Size];
                dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);
                await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(mediaFile, buffer);
                UpdateRecordingControls(RecordingMode.Initializing);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand the following sentence in your question: *, I am curious to know How can we change the byte[] data to replicate different crazy sounds or voices.*, could you explain a bit better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically, recognize the voice and change the voice to something new..like Talking Tom app

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) to do this. It actually is a complete library that will help you manage audio files.

[Here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-resample-audio-with-naudio.html) is a basic tutorial by [Mark Heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7532/mark-heath) on how to use NAudio to resample audio files.